# If statement in constructor not working as intended? Java

Tags: java, class, if-statement, constructor

this is the constructor I am using in my parent class:

```
    public Base(String breadType, String meat) {
    this.breadType = breadType;
    this.meat = meat;

    if(!this.breadType.equals("baguette")|| !this.breadType.equals("brown rye")) {
        this.additionalCost+= 1.99;
        System.out.println("Bread neither baguette or brown rye.");
    }
    if(!this.breadType.equals("beef") || !this.breadType.equals("low-fat meat")) {
        this.additionalCost+= 2.99;
        System.out.println("Meat neither beef or low-fat meat.");

    }


    this.finalCost = baseCost+additionalCost;

}
```

So to clarify, the logic I am trying to create is that it checks if the input was either 'baguette' or 'brown rye'. If it is NOT either of these, then the additionalCost field will be incremented by 1.99. A similar logic has been implemented for the type of meat being inputted.

I have a child class with the following Constructor:

```
    public Healthy_Burger() {
        super("brown rye","low-fat meat");
        //addCost(this.baseCost-super.getBaseCost());
    }
```

Unless I have understood super() in constructors incorrectly, I would have thought that the arguments I entered would be then passed in the base Constructor 'Base' which is followed by the if statements, which then checks if the bread or meat is not the ones it is looking for and if it isn't, it should increment additionalCost with the respective value.

Ultimately, my issue is that when I instantiate a 'Healthy_Burger' like so:

```
    Healthy_Burger burger = new Healthy_Burger();
```

I even used getters to ensure the breadType is 'brown rye', but the issue I am having is that upon checking the final Cost, I am seeing that the additionalCosts of both the breadType and Meat are being added, even though they aren't meant to because the bread type is 'brown rye' and the meat 'low-fat meat' and my if statement should therefore not return true.

Thank you.

Comment: `if(!this.breadType.equals("baguette") && !this.breadType.equals("brown rye")) {`

Comment: you should use `and` not `or`

Comment: might come in handy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: also why do you check if `breadType` is equal to `"beef"`?

Comment: By using a step-by-step debugger, you would have found the answer more quickly than by posting on SO

Comment: Lino I only gave part of the code that is relevant. I need it to check beef too for another class :) Thanks everyone!!!!!

Comment: Also, since there's no null check against the incoming parameters, flipping the if-statement conditionals is a good idea `!"baguette".equals(this.breadType)`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're checking the wrong variable `breadType` instead of `meat`, and using the wrong operator `||` instead of `&&`

Change your 2nd `if` from:

```
if (!this.breadType.equals("beef") || !this.breadType.equals("low-fat meat"))
```

to:

```
if (!this.meat.equals("beef") && !this.meat.equals("low-fat meat"))
```

Comment: This isn't the issue. If you read the code, you'll find I have 2 if statements checking both of these. My issue is that both if statements are running when they're not supposed to, because my bread is 'brown rye' and meat is 'low-fat meat'.

Comment: @arrey this 100% **is** the issue. Read your code again closely. You're checking if `breadType.equals("beef")` - what are the chances that the bread type is beef? You *meant* to code `meat.equals("beef")`. That, and you're using the wrong boolean operator. Use `&&` not `||`.

Comment: @arrey thats because you are using OR. Even if bread is "brown rye", the statement is true because it is NOT "baguette"

Comment: Thank you Arthur, I didn't think about that logic error I had. Thank you all so much. Thanks Bohemian, I get what you're trying to say :)

Comment: @Bohemian I made this change, then this line started throwing an error:
        this.finalCost = baseCost+additionalCost;
It is saying for each of these fields that "Unknown class: x" x being finalCost, baseCost, and additional cost?

Comment: Never mind. Found error.

Answer (score 2):

> If it is NOT either of these, then the additionalCost field will be incremented by 1.99.

And you wrote :

```
if(!this.breadType.equals("baguette") || !this.breadType.equals("brown rye")) {
```

So that means :

> If it is NOT baguette OR NOT brown rye, then the additionalCost field will be incremented by 1.99.

You have to replace the `||` (OR) by `&&` (AND).

So the condition should be :

```
if(!this.breadType.equals("baguette") && !this.breadType.equals("brown rye")) {
```

Comment: I tried this and replaced the or by and, and tried copying your code, but the if statement is still initializing?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're saying. Are you still facing any error ?

Comment: Essentially yes. I'll update what I said above:
for this line of code
        finalCost = baseCost+additionalCost;
I am getting an error for each field - 'Unknown Class: x' where x is finalCost, baseCost, and additionalCost.

Comment: Never mind. Extra curly-bracket was causing it. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You should use && instead of ||,

```
    if(!this.breadType.equals("baguette")&& !this.breadType.equals("brown rye")) {
    this.additionalCost+= 1.99;
    System.out.println("Bread neither baguette or brown rye.");
}
if(!this.breadType.equals("beef") && !this.breadType.equals("low-fat meat")) {
    this.additionalCost+= 2.99;
    System.out.println("Meat neither beef or low-fat meat.");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!this.breadType.equals("baguette") && !this.breadType.equals("brown rye")) {
        this.additionalCost+= 1.99;
        System.out.println("Bread neither baguette or brown rye.");
}
```

Your if statement returns true for the first parameter (as it is not equal to baguette) and due to the OR statement (`||`) it gets executed anyway.
Try an AND (`&&`) instead of the OR because you only want to add the cost if it is neither of the types.